# Why does clip-path (and other properties) affect the stacking order (z-index) of elements later in DOM?

Tags: css, clip-path

This has been asked before, but only where `z-index` is explictly defined in the CSS.

I am trying to use clip-path on a heading, but then pull up an image from within an element beneath this back over the top of that header.  However, as soon as I define a `clip-path` on the header, the image (which should be higher up the stacking order as it appears later in the code) goes **underneath the header**:

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
}

header {
  background: #a00;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 5em), 0 100%);
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2em;
  font: 300%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  background: #ccc;
  padding-top:5em;
  margin-top:-5em;
}

img {
  margin-top: -10em;
  
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Header Content</h1>
</header>

<section>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/330/0000FF/808080"/>
</section>
```

I would expect the image to be **above** the header.  After playing around some more, I found that if I set `position:relative` on the image - it works:

```css
body {
      padding: 1em;
    }

    header {
      background: #a00;
      clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 5em), 0 100%);
    }

    h1 {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 2em;
      font: 300%;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
    }

    section {
      background: #ccc;
      padding-top:5em;
      margin-top:-5em;
    }

    img {
      margin-top: -10em;
      position:relative;
    }
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Header Content</h1>
</header>

<section>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/330/0000FF/808080"/>
</section>
```

But why?  What's happening here please and why does clip-path appear to affect the stacking order of elements later in the page?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path#Values and read the note

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the specifcation](https://drafts.fxtf.org/css-masking-1/#the-clip-path):

> A computed value of other than none results in the creation of a stacking context  the same way **that CSS opacity  does for values other than 1**.

Then considering [the painting order](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-css-position-3-20160517/#painting-order):

> 8. All positioned, opacity or transform descendants, in tree order that fall into the following categories:
>
>    1. All positioned descendants with 'z-index: auto' or 'z-index: 0', in tree order.
>       For those with 'z-index: auto', treat the element as if it created a new stacking context, but any positioned descendants and descendants which actually create a new stacking context should be considered part of the parent stacking context, not this new one.
>       For those with 'z-index: 0' treat the stacking context generated atomically.
>    2. **All opacity descendants with opacity less than 1, in tree order, create a stacking context generated atomically.**
>    3. All transform descendants with transform other than none, in tree order, create a stacking context generated atomically.

The element with `clip-path` is painted at the step (8) and the image will be painted before if has no position set

> 4. For all **its in-flow, non-positioned**, block-level descendants in tree order: If the element is a block, list-item, or other block equivalent ...

---

If you add `position:relative` to image it will be postioned and will fall under the step (8) and the tree order will decide making it above the `clip-path` element

Here is the same code with `opacity` where you will have the same painting order:

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
}

header {
  background: #a00;
  opacity:0.8;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2em;
  font: 300%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  background: #ccc;
  padding-top:5em;
  margin-top:-5em;
}

img {
  margin-top: -10em;
  
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Header Content</h1>
</header>

<section>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/330/0000FF/808080"/>
</section>
```

---

Related:

[Why does position:relative; appear to change the z-index?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52694564/8620333)

[Why can't an element with a z-index value cover its child?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54897916/8620333)

---

Many other properties behave the same way and oblige your element to be painted at the step (8):

- `filter` <sup>[ref](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects-1/#FilterProperty)</sup>
- `backdrop-filter` <sup>[ref](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects-2/#BackdropFilterProperty)</sup>
- `perspective` <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-2/#propdef-perspective)</sup>
- `mix-blend-mode` <sup>[ref](https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing-1/#mix-blend-mode)</sup>
- `mask` <sup>[ref](https://drafts.fxtf.org/css-masking/#the-mask-image)</sup>

Comment: any solution for clip-path element to appear above its child element?

Comment: @VishalBhatt what do you mean? can you show an example

Comment: thanks for asking. Actually I have dropped that idea and found another work around.

Comment: @TemaniAfif when you click on the link **painting order**, the message appears : This version is outdated! For the latest version, please look at https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/. but the link they give no longer offers the painting order. I would like to know why

Comment: @Oceangermanique they removed the painting order from that part of the Spec to re-write it that's why I am linking an old version. You can refer to this one: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/zindex.html but it doesn't include the part I need