# One element's position is absolute, the other's position is relative, which one is the upper

Tags: css

I'm new in css. I confused in position. There is a simple example.

https://jsfiddle.net/4t8zn9yo/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.content').scroll(function() {
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
     if (!$('.topline').hasClass('long'))
       $('.topline').addClass('long')
    } else {
     if ($('.topline').hasClass('long'))
       $('.topline').removeClass('long')
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.header {
  position: relative;
  height: 65px;
  background: brown;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
  
.topline {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 5px;
  background: blue;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.topline.long {
  height: 65px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.topbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.topbar div {
  flex: 1;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  height: calc(100vh - 65px);
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.content-parta {
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='header'>
 <div class='topline'>
  
  </div>
  <div class='topbar'>
    <div>test1</div>
    <div>test2</div>
    <div>test3</div>
    <div>test4</div>
  </div>
 
</div>
<div class='content'>
  <div class='content-parta'>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

When scroll event trigger, topline class is higher than topbar class. I have no idea why the son of topbar class is higher than topline class.

When I move the topline class after the topbar class, it is the highest.

I want to know why.

Comment: It's because of the [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).  If you want top line above top bar without moving them, then use a z-index

Comment: @Pete Thanks! It help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refer to [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html) and the painting order:

> 8. All **positioned**, opacity or transform descendants, **in tree order** that fall into the following categories:

1. **All positioned descendants with 'z-index: auto'** or 'z-index: 0', in tree order.
   For those with 'z-index: auto', treat the element as if it created a new stacking context, but any positioned descendants and descendants which actually create a new stacking context should be considered part of the parent stacking context, not this new one.

Both elements are positionned with the same properties (`z-index:auto` is the important one) so the tree order will decide which one will be on the top. In your actual code `topbar` is on the top. If you switch the HTML order you will have it on the bottom:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.content').scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
        if (!$('.topline').hasClass('long'))
        $('.topline').addClass('long')
    } else {
        if ($('.topline').hasClass('long'))
        $('.topline').removeClass('long')
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.header {
  position: relative;
  height: 65px;
  background: brown;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
  
.topline {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 5px;
  background: blue;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.topline.long {
  height: 65px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.topbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background:red;
}

.topbar div {
  flex: 1;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  height: calc(100vh - 65px);
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.content-parta {
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='header'>
 <div class='topline'>
  
  </div>
  <div class='topbar'>
    <div>test1</div>
    <div>test2</div>
    <div>test3</div>
    <div>test4</div>
  </div>
 
</div>
<div class='content'>
  <div class='content-parta'>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

If you remove the position from one element, whataver the tree order the other positionned element will always be on the top.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.content').scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
        if (!$('.topline').hasClass('long'))
        $('.topline').addClass('long')
    } else {
        if ($('.topline').hasClass('long'))
        $('.topline').removeClass('long')
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.header {
  position: relative;
  height: 65px;
  background: brown;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
  
.topline {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 5px;
  background: blue;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.topline.long {
  height: 65px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.topbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background:red;
}

.topbar div {
  flex: 1;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  height: calc(100vh - 65px);
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.content-parta {
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='header'>
 <div class='topline'>
  
  </div>
  <div class='topbar'>
    <div>test1</div>
    <div>test2</div>
    <div>test3</div>
    <div>test4</div>
  </div>
 
</div>
<div class='content'>
  <div class='content-parta'>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Related:

[Why can't an element with a z-index value cover its child?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54897916/8620333)

[Why does position:relative; appear to change the z-index?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52694564/8620333)

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand it a little!

Answer (score 0):

HTML thinks that it is now behind. Think of it as a 3 dimensional environment. You can use z-index. This way you can control how the appearance works. You can check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index) out.

Comment: Thanks! I will use z-index!