# Any purpose to a parent container being positioned relative if no absolute/relative position declarations are expressed in descendants

Tags: html, css

In an application I am working I found a top level parent container with `position: relative` like so:

```
<div style="position: relative">
    <!--render body content here-->
</div>
```

Many HTML views are rendered in this parent container. Not single HTML has absolute positioning.

This is not my code, so I want to make sure that the inline CSS `style="position: relative"` serves no purpose and can be deleted.

There isn't a point to a parent container have `position:relative` if there is not descendants with `position:absolute` or `position:relative`, correct? As there is not any child container that has position defined at all, that I can find.

Comment: Nope. You can move a relative positioned element using top, right, bottom or left. You can also set it's z-index value, so it will be above static elements, or elements with z-index.

Comment: @OriDrori no descendant is relative either I will update my question

Comment: it affect the painting order: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52698754/8620333 so it doesn't need to contain child with particular properties. An element with position:relative will be painted later that a one without. But without your full code no one can say if it's useless or not.