# Why is image not being set to background? using ::before

Tags: css

I am trying to set the background of the body to an image using `background-image`, and I have content that I want to be placed on top of the image. In the CSS, I am setting the background using the `body` selector with the `::before` pseudo-element; however, the image doesn't come in the background unless if I use `z-index: -1`. (I am using `::before` because I want to fix the image to the viewport, and I don't want to do that in the regular `body` selector as that will fix all the content on the page and prevent me from scrolling through the content.)

```css
body::before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: url(...);
}

form {
  background: purple;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <form></form>

</body>

</html>
```

My question is: Why do I need to set the z-index to -1 in order for the image to appear in the background? Why doesn't it appear in the background automatically "before" all the content? Isn't that what the purpose of `::before` is?

Answer (score 1):

A bit tricky part here. First `::before` doesn't mean that this pseudo element goes precisely before `form` element. In fact this means create pseudo element before any children of `form` element. Vice versa for `::after`. Second you set `position: fixed;` for `::before` thats create new stacking context for it - simple this is the reason (not really check: [Why does position:relative; appear to change the z-index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52694564/why-does-positionrelative-appear-to-change-the-z-index)) why it overlaps the content of `form` element.

**UPD**
Probably you should use `background-attachment: fixed;` on body element https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp

Comment: The before is set on body not form element

Comment: the creation of stacking context is not linked to the fact that it overlap the content

Comment: What is the reason then?

Comment: it's the painting order, check the duplicate I added